# How to read the xml Declaration with groovy xmlSlurper

Tags: xml, encoding, groovy, xmlslurper

I'm currently having trouble with reading some xml files that have different encodings.
Therefore I'm trying to get the encoding out of the xml Declaration.

I know that to create the Declaration you use root.mkp.xmlDeclaration(version:"1.0", encoding:"UTF-8")
But I couldn't find a way to read it.

greetings

Comment: If your call to parse passes a `File` or `InputStream` it should  autodetect the encoding. If you pass a `String` or a `Reader` it won't

Comment: I think he might be trying, after parsing, to output what encoding was detected, maybe for debug purposes.

Comment: Here's a comment I saw in similiar post - read the file as text and read the first line and parse it out, possibly with a regex, then close the file.  Now use XmlSlurper to get the contents.